# How to JOIN multiple tables in mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this `queries` that JOINS 2 tables and I am planning to add more table but, I'm already having trouble with two `tables`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE JOIN crew_rank ON info.id = crew_rank.crew_rank_id WHERE info.id = ?";
  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $_GET['id']);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $full_name, $phone_number, $crew_rank,$date_of_birth,$age,$telephone_number,$vessel,$place_of_birth,$religion,$joining_date);
```

What is the problem with this `query`? I'm having an error like this

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice1\admin\edit_info_docs.php on line 9
>   (this is `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $_GET['id']);`)
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice1\admin\edit_info_docs.php on line 10
>   (this is `mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);`)
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice1\admin\edit_info_docs.php on line 11
>   (this is `mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $full_name, $phone_number, $crew_rank,$date_of_birth,$age,$telephone_number,$vessel,$place_of_birth,$religion,$joining_date);`)

Comment: your query is incorrect  read the documentation. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

You have a redundant `where` keyword before the `join` clause. Remove it and you should be OK:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   info
JOIN   crew_rank ON info.id = crew_rank.crew_rank_id 
WHERE  info.id = ?
```